# mupdf: Can't do incremental writes when changing encryption

Tags: python, pymupdf

I'm trying to add table of contents to the pdf using `fitz` package.

Here's my script

```
doc = fitz.open(path)
bookmarks = [[1, 'INTRODUCTION', 1], [1, 'MANUSCRIPT COMPONENTS', 1], [1, 'MULTIMEDIA FIGURES – VIDEO AND AUDIO FILES', 2], [1, 'MATHEMATICAL EQUATIONS', 3], [1, 'USING THIS TEMPLATE AND ITS AUTOMATIC FORMATTING', 3]]
doc.setToC(bookmarks) # o/p -> 5
doc.save(doc.name, incremental=True) # to save the document with added bookmarks/table of contents
# above line gives the error
```

Here is the Stack trace

```
>>> doc.save(doc.name, incremental=True)
mupdf: Can't do incremental writes when changing encryption
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\BookmarkPDF\pdfenv\lib\site-packages\fitz\fitz.py", line 4270, in save
    return _fitz.Document_save(
RuntimeError: Can't do incremental writes when changing encryption
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `PyMyPDF==1.18.17`

[PDF encryption method codes](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vars.html#encryptionmethods) no longer works, you would have to use the following to method. Please refer to the code below.

```
doc = fitz.open(path)
bookmarks = [[1, 'INTRODUCTION', 1], [1, 'MANUSCRIPT COMPONENTS', 1], [1, 'MULTIMEDIA FIGURES – VIDEO AND AUDIO FILES', 2], [1, 'MATHEMATICAL EQUATIONS', 3], [1, 'USING THIS TEMPLATE AND ITS AUTOMATIC FORMATTING', 3]]
doc.setToC(bookmarks) # o/p -> 5
doc.save(doc.name, incremental=True, encryption=0)
```

You would have to give `encryption` the value of `0` which apperantly fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

`doc.save()` uses `encryption=PDF_ENCRYPT_NONE` by default [(see documentation here)](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.save). Your document must have some type of encryption, which `doc.save` is attempting to remove (i.e. change to none).

Knowing this, the error is self explanatory: `fitz` cannot save incrementally *and* change the encryption.

You expressed no desire to change encryption in your question/code, so you can specify to keep it.

To do this, you can use:

```
 doc.save(doc.name, incremental=True, encryption=PDF_ENCRYPT_KEEP).
```

Or you can also use `doc.saveIncr()` as a convenience abbreviation [(see here for docs)](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.saveIncr).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it using lower version of PYmuPDF.
pip install PyMuPDF==1.14.20